# How to configure GeoWebCache that it can generate tile files conform Slippy Map format

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

The tile files generated by GeoWebCache using gridset 900913 are like: \EPSG_90013_6\02_02\0032_42.png, etc.

How can I configure GeoWebCache that it is generating the files conform slippy map format? That is \6\32\21.png, etc.

Comment: Why not just configure the application that uses the tiles to use a different URL format rather than change the back-end?

Comment: @geographika: one possible usage would be to generate tiles with Geoserver but serve the tiles using other software (ArcGis).

Comment: @user2562: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy configuration option to do so but I believe the "backend storage" in geowebcache is pluggable... so it might be possible to write a custom storage backend that uses the same format as slippy map. I would post to the geowebcache-devel list and ask there.