# Setting up tile map server

Tags: geoserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure GeoWebCache that it can generate tile files conform Slippy Map format](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8140/how-to-configure-geowebcache-that-it-can-generate-tile-files-conform-slippy-map)

With my little knowledge on geoserver, I need to setup a server with can use local tiles of 256x256 size and in jpeg format. The format of directory structure is z/x/y. I tried using the options available in geoserver, but did n't get success. Could anyone guide me with steps to be followed to setup this?

Comment: have you created your own tiles yet or wanting geoserver to do so?

Comment: you might have more luck here: http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/GeoServer-User-f3786390.html Several GeoServer and GeoWebCache developers are active on the User mailing list

Comment: Yes, I already have tile cache with z/x/y format/folder structure. I will go through the links provided by you and come back if any help needed.